# How can I get the fully qualified namespace from a using directive in Roslyn?

Tags: c#, roslyn

When you hover over a "simplified" `using` directive in VS2015, it shows you the fully-qualified name. How would I get this information via a Roslyn plugin? Would it be using a `DiagnosticAnalyzer`? A `CodeFixProvider`?

Reading through source.roslyn.codeplex.com, there's tons of information there, including how to [add a `using` statement](http://source.roslyn.codeplex.com/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Features/CodeFixes/AddImport/CSharpAddImportCodeFixProvider.cs), and also how to simplify type names (including `using` statements), but I'm unable to figure out how to go in reverse to get the fully-qualified name.

Comment: I assume you'll have to use the semanticmodel to retrieve the type it refers to and then find out it's fully qualified name using `.ToDisplayString()`.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel: you should write that as an answer. ;-)

Comment: @JasonMalinowski I was preoccupied but I've added one now ;-) Perhaps you can clarify what `SymbolDisplayFormat` should be used? I didn't expect `SymbolDisplayFormat.FullyQualifiedFormat` to include the `global::` prefix

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With the semantic model you can retrieve information about the semantics that make up your code (evidently) -- this allows you to get specific information about types and other constructs.

For example:

```
void Main()
{
    var tree = CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(@"
using X = System.Text;
using Y = System;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
}"
);

    var mscorlib = PortableExecutableReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(object).Assembly.Location);
    var compilation = CSharpCompilation.Create("MyCompilation", syntaxTrees: new[] { tree }, references: new[] { mscorlib });
    var semanticModel = compilation.GetSemanticModel(tree);
    var root = tree.GetRoot();

    // Get usings
    foreach (var usingDirective in root.DescendantNodes().OfType<UsingDirectiveSyntax>())
    {
        var symbol = semanticModel.GetSymbolInfo(usingDirective.Name).Symbol;
        var name = symbol.ToDisplayString(SymbolDisplayFormat.FullyQualifiedFormat);
        name.Dump();
    }
}
```

Output:

> global::System.Text
>   global::System
>   global::System.IO

If you use `SymbolDisplayFormat.CSharpErrorMessageFormat` instead, you will receive

> System.Text
>   System
>   System.IO

Your choice what you're interested in but as you can see it works just fine with aliases and without.

Comment: I should have included my sample code; got to the point of `root.DescendantNodes().OfType<UsingDirectiveSyntax>()` and then couldn't figure out what to do with the node after. I tried `.Name` and casting it to `QualifiedNameSyntax` and then got totally lost.

Comment: The sample `DiagnosticAnalyzer` I was working with didn't include the semantic model, so I had started looking into `CodeFixProvider` instead.

Comment: I suggest you read through Josh Varty's excellent walkthroughs on these concepts -- they will clarify what is what exactly. https://joshvarty.wordpress.com/learn-roslyn-now/