# Fully Qualified Namespace Metadata Error with Roslyn

Tags: c#, location, metadata, roslyn, fully-qualified-naming

I am trying to make a code analyzer which checks for fully qualified using statements.  This link has been incredibly helpful, and the basis for my solution ([How can I get the fully qualified namespace from a using directive in Roslyn?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36407563/how-can-i-get-the-fully-qualified-namespace-from-a-using-directive-in-roslyn)) but I am running into a problem when I try to access the location of the symbol for the using directive.  My code looks like this:

```
    private static void AnalyzeModel(SemanticModelAnalysisContext semanticModelAnalysisContext)
    {
        var semanticModel = semanticModelAnalysisContext.SemanticModel;
        var root = semanticModel.SyntaxTree.GetRoot();

        // compare each using statement's name with its fully qualified name
        foreach (var usingDirective in root.DescendantNodes().OfType<UsingDirectiveSyntax>())
        {
            var symbol = semanticModel.GetSymbolInfo(usingDirective.Name).Symbol;
            var fullyQualifiedName = symbol.ToDisplayString(SymbolDisplayFormat.FullyQualifiedFormat);

            if (fullyQualifiedName.Contains(GlobalTag))
            {
                fullyQualifiedName = fullyQualifiedName.Substring(GlobalTag.Length);
            }

            if (usingDirective.Name.ToString() != fullyQualifiedName)
            {
                // for each name that is not fully qualified, produce a diagnostic.
                var diagnostic = Diagnostic.Create(Rule, symbol.Locations[0], symbol.Name);
                semanticModelAnalysisContext.ReportDiagnostic(diagnostic);
            }
        }
    }
```

The problem is the `symbol.Locations[0]` only contains items in metadata, not items in source.  This leads to the following error:

`Assert.IsTrue failed. Test base does not currently handle diagnostics in metadata locations.`

My source in my unit tests looks like this:

`private const string incorrectSourceCode = @"
                namespace System 
                {
                    using IO;
                    using Threading;
                }";`

Why are there no items in `symbol.Locations` that are in source?  Is there another place I can get this location?  I've tried using `symbol.ContainingSymbol.Locations[0]` or `symbol.ContainingNamespace.Locations[0]`, but those are not referring to the using specific using that I am interested in. I've been pulling out my hair over this for hours, and some clarity would be very greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Symbol` contains `MetadateLocation`, so if you want to see `SourceLocation` just retrieve it from the appropriate `SyntaxNode`:

```
var diagnostic = Diagnostic.Create(Rule, usingDirective.Name.GetLocation(), symbol.Name)
```

instead of

```
var diagnostic = Diagnostic.Create(Rule, symbol.Locations[0], symbol.Name)
```

Comment: This solution worked like a charm. Thank you so much for sharing your knowledge, you are a kind soul. :)